# Unable to install Docker Desktop 3.0.0 onto Windows Server 2019 DataCenter

Tags: windows, docker, server, docker-desktop, windows-server-2019

I have downloaded the latest release of Docker Desktop from the official source and I'm trying to install onto a new production server. The install seems to fail when creating the service, although when I check the Docker Desktop service is present however wont start (because Docker Desktop removes all installed files once install fails).

There is basically no information that I can see on why this is failing. As far as I am aware I have all pre-requisites installed. Below is the install log from the last failed attempt:

```
Started on: 2020/12/18 13:20:52.776
File: C:\Users\willc\AppData\Local\Docker\install-log.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Users\willc\Desktop\Docker Desktop Installer.exe" 
[13:20:52.792][ManifestAndExistingInstallationLoader] No install path specified, looking for default installation registry key
[13:20:52.792][Program] No installation found
[13:20:52.886][InstallWorkflow] Using package: res:DockerDesktop
[13:20:52.886][InstallWorkflow] Downloading
[13:21:02.214][InstallWorkflow] Extracting manifest
[13:21:04.132][InstallWorkflow] Manifest found: version=50684, displayVersion=3.0.0, channelUrl=https://desktop.docker.com/win/stable/appcast.xml
[13:21:04.133][InstallWorkflow] Checking prerequisites
[13:21:05.110][InstallWorkflow] Prompting for optional features
[13:21:11.067][InstallWorkflow] Unpacking artifacts
[13:23:27.010][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[13:23:27.121][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[13:23:27.130][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction
[13:23:29.224][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction
[13:23:29.228][InstallWorkflow-ServiceAction] Removing service
[13:23:29.234][InstallWorkflow-ServiceAction] Creating service
[13:23:59.288][InstallWorkflow] Installation failed
Exception type: System.Exception, Exception message: Component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction failed: Failed to start service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion, StackTrace:
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
[13:23:59.292][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction
[13:23:59.294][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[13:23:59.296][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[13:23:59.298][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.UnpackArtifactsStep
[13:23:59.307][FileSystem] Deleting C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker
[13:23:59.703][FileSystem] Deleted C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker successfully
[13:23:59.704][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ExtractManifestStep
[13:23:59.705][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.DownloadStep
```

Has anyone experience anything similar?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, sadly I haven't been able to fix it. Check out some of suggestions here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6091.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is simple, Docker Desktop cannot be installed onto windows server, it took me a while to find this info on the official website.

Our remaining options were Docker Enterprise or Azure Docker.